# Why Do My Obstacles Do This In My Object Pooler?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, pool, eventtrigger

I am almost done with my Object Pooling System for my PickAxe GameObject, but I have this one problem I need help with.

What I am trying to figure out is why all of my spawning restarts whenever the first PickAxe hits the wall? How do I make to where the PickAxe just goes back into the "pooler" whenever it hits the wall?

I took two screenshots and I'll post my code below too. The first one is just before the first Pickaxe that was spawned hits the wall, and the second screenshot is right after that same PickAxe hit the wall.
[image: Before the wall is hit]

[image: After the wall is hit]

Some of my code below:

This script spawns my PickAxes. I am 99% sure my problem is where I am calling my Event function in my CoRoutine. Am I right?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]

public class Obstacle4 // Pick Axe Obstacle
{
    public float SpawnWait; // Time in seconds between next wave of obstacle 4.
    public float StartGameWait; // Time in seconds between when the game starts and when the fourth obstacle start spawning.
    public float WaveSpawnWait; // Time in seconds between waves when the next wave of obstacle 4 will spawn.
}

public class SpawnPickAxe : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject pickAxePrefab;

    public Obstacle4 obstacle4_;

    void Start () 
    {

        PickAxePoolManager.instance.CreatePool (pickAxePrefab, 15); //CreatePool is a method in PickAxePoolManager

        StartCoroutine (PickAxeSpawner ());
    }


    IEnumerator PickAxeSpawner () 
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (obstacle4_.StartGameWait);
        while (true) 
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            {

                Vector3 newSpawnPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 1.2f, 30.0f);
                Quaternion newSpawnRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f);     
                PickAxePoolManager.instance.ReuseObject (pickAxePrefab, newSpawnPosition, newSpawnRotation); //ReuseObject is also a method in PickAxePoolManager
                //Instantiate (obstacle4.pickAxe, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (obstacle4_.SpawnWait);

                ResetByWall.instance.onTriggerEntered += delegate(GameObject obj) 
                {
                    PickAxePoolManager.instance.ReuseObject(pickAxePrefab, newSpawnPosition, newSpawnRotation);
                };
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (obstacle4_.WaveSpawnWait);
        }

    }

}
```

Below is my "ResetByWall" script. This script is also important because it contains the public Event that allows me to detect a collision with whatever collides with my wall, and my wall is the trigger.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResetByWall : MonoBehaviour 
{

    //public bool collided;

    //public GameObject pickAxePrefab;

    //NOTE:
    //Singleton Pattern from lines 12 to 25 //
    // ************************************

    static ResetByWall _instance; // Reference to the Reset By Wall script

    public static ResetByWall instance  // This is the accessor
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_instance == null)   // Check to see if _instance is null
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<ResetByWall>(); //Find the instance in the Reset By Wall script in the currently active scene
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public event Action <GameObject> onTriggerEntered;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (onTriggerEntered != null) {
            onTriggerEntered (other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my PoolManager Script. You might not even need to look at this script but I'll post it anyways just in case.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PickAxePoolManager : MonoBehaviour {

    Dictionary<int,Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary = new Dictionary<int,Queue<GameObject>>();

    //NOTE: 
    //Singleton Pattern used from lines 12 to 25

    static PickAxePoolManager _instance; // Reference to the Pool Manager script

    public static PickAxePoolManager instance   // This is the accessor
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_instance == null)   // Check to see if _instance is null
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<PickAxePoolManager>(); //Find the instance in the Pool Manager script in the currently active scene
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the pool.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prefab">Prefab.</param>
    /// <param name="poolSize">Pool size.</param>

    public void CreatePool(GameObject prefab, int poolSize)
    {
        int poolKey = prefab.GetInstanceID ();  // Unique integer for every GameObject

        if (!poolDictionary.ContainsKey (poolKey))   //Make sure poolKey is not already in the Dictionary, 
            //if it's not then we can create the pool 
        {
            poolDictionary.Add(poolKey, new Queue<GameObject>());

            for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++)  //Instantiate the prefabs as dictated by the "poolSize" integer
            {
                GameObject newObject = Instantiate (prefab) as GameObject;  //Instantiate as a GameObject
                newObject.SetActive(false);  // Don't want it to be visible in the scene yet
                poolDictionary [poolKey].Enqueue(newObject);    // Add it to our Pool
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your singletons called initially in a single threaded fashion? Because there is a race condition where multiple threads can get `true` on your `if(_instance == null)` so each would run the code inside the block (I can't tell if this is even a problem, it depends on how your `FindObjectOfType<>` code works). Also I can't tell what the problem is.. the pickaxes look to be in roughly the same location in both screenshots, but judging from your text I assume the problem is that all pickaxes are in a certain position, but when one hits the wall they all move to some "pooler" location?

Comment: If I understand your terminology correctly, then no my singletons are not called initially in a single threaded fashion. And I am sorry, I should have waited a couple more seconds before I took that second screenshot! I promise, though, that the PickAxes' positions are different in both of those screenshots. I am so sure that this problem arose in my onTriggerEntered event function or in the way I called that Event in my PickAxe Spawner Script. @Quantic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I am just going to use this in my ResetByWall script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider obstacle)
    {
        if (obstacle.gameObject.tag == "Pick Axe")
        {
            obstacle.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: use `obstacle.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Axe")` instead of `obstacle.gameObject.tag == "Pick Axe"`, the CompareTag function has optimisations built in and [compiles to fewer instructions](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200820/is-comparetag-better-than-gameobjecttag-performanc.html).